# Написать программу при помощи оператора цикла for

Tags: c++, for

Написать код при помощи оператора цикла `for` (без применения массивов и прямой адресации курсора) для распечатки на экране монитора указанного в варианте набора символов.
Результат который должен получиться на картинке. Вот пример кода:
[image: 1]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() // ПОДРОБНЫЙ ВАРИАНТ ЗАПИСИ ПРОГРАММЫ
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;    /* Счетчики */
    char c = 'A'; /* Переменная для хранения значения первого символа в строке */
    // Цикл по строкам
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
        { /* Начало тела цикла печати строки */
            if (c > 'I')
            {
                c = 'A'; /*** 1) Проверка значения символа */
            }
            cout << c << " "; /*** 2) Вывод символа на экран */
            c++; c++; /*** 3) Новое значение символа */
        }
        cout << endl;
        /**** III) Подготовка первого символа следующей строки */
        c--;
        c--;
    } /* Конец действий внутри цикла по строкам */
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: .. и в чем состоит ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Устроит](https://ideone.com/gUd299)?

```
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; cout << "\n", ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            cout<< char('A'+((i==j)?0:(i>j)?4-j:j)) << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Да, большое спасибо. Долго не мог додуматься